# How do i make Chrome use an IPv6 address from my hosts file?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, ipv6, hosts-file

I have a Windows 7 machine that's running Ubuntu in a VM.  The VM has an interface configured as an IPv6-only, host-only network.  The network is statically set up, and all that seems to be working.  Both machines can see and ping each other by IP.

I've also given the VM a couple of names in the Windows machine's hosts file, like this:

```
fddc:db0e:57e9:e33b::1  sitename
```

I can ping the VM by name, and using Firefox or IE, can even visit the sites by name.  But Chrome refuses to see them.  I've tried `http://sitename` and `http://sitename.`, and i get nothing but a page that says "This webpage is not available", and at the bottom (after i click "More"), says "Error code: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED".

At first glance, it looks like Chrome's totally ignoring the hosts file entry.  `chrome://net-internals/#dns` seems to say IPv6 is enabled (the list at the top shows "Default address family: UNSPECIFIED"), but the name is listed in the DNS cache as an unresolvable IPv4 address.

**(How) can i get Chrome to see the IPv6 addresses listed in my hosts file?**

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Have you tried another browser?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: FF and IE both work.  Chrome doesn't.  Haven't tried any other browsers (Opera being the only other one that comes to mind).  I can use FF if need be, but....eh.

Comment: Same problem after 2 years...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome not using hosts file for IPv6 addresses since v73](https://superuser.com/questions/1421602/chrome-not-using-hosts-file-for-ipv6-addresses-since-v73)